# Age of Empires III Definitive Edition not wotking with Porting Kit 5, on macOS Ventura

Tags: imac, ventura, games, wine, intel

I am encountering an issue with Age of Empires 3 Definitive Edition. I purchased the game on Steam but, on account of it only being available for Windows, I tried using Porting Kit (https://www.portingkit.com/) to play on my mac.

My setup:

- 2017 iMac, CPU: 4.2 GHz Quad-Core Intel i7, RAM: 40 GB DDR4, GPU: AMD Radeon Pro 580 with 8 GB VRAM
- macOS Ventura 13.4.1
- Wine stable 8.0.1, installed via homebrew
- Porting Kit 5.14.4

What I attempted thus far:

Library install:

- went to the Porting Kit library, searched for AOE 3 DE, and pressed install;
- the process seems to have run smoothly, with no issues;
- after the install is finished, I press Play, and I see some app with the Steam logo starting, but it is only visible in the dock
- I can see, for a short time, a little status window that displays a progress bar (Steam updating) but it goes away after a while
- there are wine processes running (confirmed with Activity Monitor) but I can't see the actual window of the application (Windows Steam)

Manual wrapper creation

- in the Porting Kit library, I click on New Custom Port
- give it a name, selected Wine (I have the experimental features activated), and then Standard Options
- in the wizard I select the latest WineCX engine at this moment "WS11WineCX64Bit22.1.1-5", check the Steam and DXVK checkboxes then go on with the creation of the wrapper
- the wizard runs its course and I get no error, but when I try to access the newly created wrapper, I get the same result as for the library install

If the experimental features are turned off, the DXVK checkbox is not displayed, so I only select Steam in the wizard, but the result is still the same.

I also tried to create a wrapper with a slightly older version of the WineCX engine (21), and in this case, Steam starts and I manage to log in and install the game. However, when I actually attempt to start the game, I see the AOE III DE splash screen and then a window appears, that says that my hardware does not support DirectX and that I have 0 MB of VRAM (even though I have 8 GB), and the "Attempt to run" button is greyed out, and all I can do is exit the game.

Could you please give me a hand in figuring out what the issue is and, maybe, how to fix it?

Thank you,
Calin

Comment: Game Porting Kit(GPT) is meant for game developers. Not intended for regular consumers to port games.

Comment: @JashJacob The name is misleading, Porting Kit is using WINE to install Windows games on a Mac similar to CrossOver.

Comment: Yes indeed, I edited the original post, to avoid confusion, and was going to post an explanation here but I got carried away with other stuff. The thing is that I am not referring to the Apple-provided porting kit tool, but rather the one that already existed.